# Traverse DOM tree with foreach loop

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

Need help traversing DOM tree with [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse).  If someone could take second to look at how it works, knowledgeable PHP coders should figure it out quickly if I figured it out.  Where I'm stuck is getting articles from a div on my friend's Russian basketball website.  For example, here's what a blog div looks like:

```
<div id='columnsList'><div class='item'>
  <div class='title'><a href='/ru/columns/1'>Колонка Римантаса Григаса</a></div>
  <div class='img'> <img src='/files/columns/grigas.jpg'></div>
  <div class='news'>
    <a href='/ru/news/3174'>Римантас Григас: о пути на Евробаскет (0)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/1486'>Римантас Григас: об уходе из УГМК и о ближайших планах (1)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/731'>О горниле «Финала восьми» Евролиги (0)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/421'>О новом назначении и о сборной Украины (0)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/299'>О настоящем примере для подражания (0)</a>
  </div><div style='clear:left;'></div> 
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
  <div class='title'><a href='/ru/columns/2'>Колонка Кирилла Натяжко</a></div>
  <div class='img'> <img src='/files/columns/nati.jpg'> </div>
  <div class='news'>
    <a href='/ru/news/3618'>Кирилл Натяжко: "Хорватов мы не боимся" (2)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/3113'>Кирилл Натяжко: "Необоснованная критика подарила мне дополнительную мотивацию" (1)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/2454'>Кирилл Натяжко: "Мне нечего бояться, пускай лучше боятся меня!" (6)</a>
    <a href='/ru/news/325'>Доброе утро, страна! (1)</a>
  </div><div style='clear:left;'></div> 
</div>
<div class='news'>
//More divs and links
```

This is how I can pull out the individual 'a' links and display them but what I want to do is get the div title for all of them, basically categorize them instead of having everything in a row. I can't figure it out how to do it in a foreach loop.

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=item] a[href*=news]') as $col){
   echo $col.'<br>';
}
```

I tried adding along with the first echo:

```
echo $col->parent()->prev_sibling()->prev_sibling()->a;
```

That should go back to div 'news', then another notch up to div 'img' and again up to div 'title'.  That should get the link of the first div=title.  But I get nothing.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it, without using arrays!

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=item]') as $item){
    echo $item->children(0)->plaintext;
    foreach ($item->find('a[href*=news]') as $col){
      echo $col.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Got the desired result!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$output = array();
foreach($html->find('div[class=item]' as $item) {
   $title = $item->find('div[class=title] a', 0)->innertext;
   $output[$title] = array();
   foreach($item->find('div[class=news] a') as $link) {
       $output[$title][] = $link->innertext;
   }
}
```

Comment: Nothing.  Source code empty.  Can you talk me through it?  What you're saying is foreach item class, get the first a link, correct?  Then you set the output array to that title 'a' link and looping just within that title div?  I'm struggling with arrays right now...

Comment: Duh, it's empty.  Because there is no echo statement.  Can you update with an echo statement?  Would I echo output[$title][]?

Comment: do `var_dump($output);` to see what it contains in the end.

Comment: This is the format it gave out: array(1){["the title"]=>array(1){[0]"and the first article"}}array(1)
Then for array two it shows the [0] and appends [1] to it.  Same for the second so it duplicates and triplicates (if that's a word) and so on.

Comment: Your question was related to Simple HTML Dom Parser, so I leave remaining details to your attention, it is obvious that you need corresponding PHP knowledge to use the result afterwards.

Comment: Got the answer. Check it out.  It was as simple as that.  Thanks for the nested loop advice.  I tried it before but in the wrong manner.  Talking through your loop helped me out with mine.